# How I can set the default language in flutter using easy localization?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to set the Arabic 'ar' the default language for my app, but it still launch in English.

Here's my code in the runApp in main.dart

```
runApp(
  EasyLocalization(
    supportedLocales: [
      Locale('en'),
      Locale('ar'),
    ],
    fallbackLocale: Locale('en'),
    assetLoader: CodegenLoader(),
    path: 'assets/translations',
    startLocale: Locale('ar'),
    child: MyApp(),
  ),
);
```

Comment: did you find any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can read this, step by step :

https://blog.logrocket.com/internationalizing-app-flutter-easy-localization/

It is well explained.